# Can we obtain the following variation of Poincaré inequality?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

The known Poincaré inequality says that in the conditions of the theorem we have
\begin{equation}
\|u - u_{\Omega}\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)} \le C \| \nabla u \|_{L^{p}(\Omega)}.
\end{equation}
see for instance [1]
Can we obatain also
\begin{equation}
\|u - u_{\Omega}\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)} \le C \| \nabla u - (\nabla  u)_{\Omega} \|_{L^{p}(\Omega)}.
\end{equation}

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; take $u(x) = a\cdot x$ for some constant vector $a$. Then the right side vanishes but the left does not.